# How am I losing POST data within my PayPal IPN script..?

Tags: php, apache, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm working with PayPal IPN.  I'm using a script I've used for years and have never had any issues with it, however, now I'm working with the MassPay API and including 250 on a single request.  As such, the IPN data sent is much larger than what I typically deal with, and somehow I'm losing data.

Within my IPN script, the first thing I'm doing is serializing the POST data and saving it to a TEXT field in MySQL.  I don't get any errors from PHP or MySQL when I do this and the data shows up in my table just fine, however, it's missing almost half of the data that was actually included with the POST when I compare it to what shows up in the PayPal IPN History log.

Outside of saving the raw IPN data, I'm also looping through all MassPay items within my script to process the payments individually.  Here's a PHP snippet of how I'm compiling all of the individual mass payments within the IPN...

```
// Mass Payments   
$i = 1;   
$mass_payments = array();   
while(isset($_POST['masspay_txn_id_' . $i]))   
{   
 $masspay_txn_id = isset($_POST['masspay_txn_id_' . $i]) ? $_POST['masspay_txn_id_' . $i] : '';   
 $mc_currency = isset($_POST['mc_currency_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_currency_' . $i] : '';   
 $mc_fee = isset($_POST['mc_fee_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_fee_' . $i] : 0;   
 $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;   
 $receiver_email = isset($_POST['receiver_email_' . $i]) ? $_POST['receiver_email_' . $i] : '';   
 $status = isset($_POST['status_' . $i]) ? $_POST['status_' . $i] : '';   
 $unique_id = isset($_POST['unique_id_' . $i]) ? $_POST['unique_id_' . $i] : '';   

 $current_payment_data_set = array(   
          'masspay_txn_id' => $masspay_txn_id,   
          'mc_currency' => $mc_currency,   
          'mc_fee' => $mc_fee,   
          'mc_gross' => $mc_gross,   
          'receiver_email' => $receiver_email,   
          'status' => $status,   
          'unique_id' => $unique_id  
         );   

 array_push($mass_payments, $current_payment_data_set);   
 $i++;   
}
```

Again, I don't get any PHP warnings, notices, errors, etc. and the IPN script completes successfully with a 200 OK result, however, half of the payment records in my system don't get updated like they should because they aren't including in what I'm getting from PayPal somehow.  The ones that do show up in my IPN data that I receive get updated as expected in my system.

Again, when I check the PayPal IPN History it shows me that the IPN included all of the data I seem to be missing, and when I compare the two the one in IPN history h as everything starting from masspay_txn_id_1 through masspay_txn_id_250.  It has unique ID's for everything, etc.  My script is only seeing unique ID's 100 - 199, though, and it's leaving out lots of other general things like txn_type.

Are there any server settings or anything that could be causing me to lose POST data even though I'm not getting any errors anywhere?

**UPDATE** 
I wound up taking what PayPal IPN History showed, which includes everything, and I placed that into a PHP script that POSTs the data to my IPN listener.  I'm still losing the data, though, so somehow my server is truncating the POST data but not giving me any warnings or anything.  I'm not finding any information on what could be causing this or how to fix it, though..??

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: do `var_dump($mass_payments)` after the loop completes and see what's coming out of your code. make sure the data's there before it heads off to paypal. And note that loop will terminate at the **FIRST** missing number, so if your fields do a jump (say, 99 => 101), that missing 100 will cause the loop to abort and bail early.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you..??  This is data I'm receiving from PayPal, not sending them.  At least not at this point.

I'm using the MassPay API to generate the payments, and when I double check the request generated there it does indeed have all the payments I expect.  

The masspay transaction in the PayPal account correctly breaks down all of the payments, too, and shows how many were completed, unclaimed, etc, so that's all good.

It's just that somehow I'm losing data without any errors/notices from PHP.

Comment: I'm wondering if somehow even though PayPal IPN history shows all of the data it's not actually sending it all.  Maybe somehow the PayPal system is logging what it's going to send, but then when it sends it it's getting truncated or something like that.  There's just no way for me to prove that, so all I can try to do is disprove that I'm losing data, but I need some troubleshooting tips for that sort of thing.

Comment: unlikely to be a problem as its text, but what is the value of your post_max_size ?

Comment: post_max_size is 100M

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('ipnlog.txt', print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Is the data there?

I recall there being an issue where IPN messages are limited to a certain byte size and get cut off, but I don't know the details.

Comment: Ok, I did this and it's saving data nicely, but I'm still only getting about 1k parameters included where IPN history in PayPal is showing that it sent me 2k+.  So either PayPal isn't sending me the data like IPN history says it is, or my server is somehow not processing all of it..??

Comment: Can't say with certainty but I believe it may only send the first 1k of data, yes.  I ran into a similar issue with line items once.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this worked out.  Turns out there's a hidden gem in PHP, max_input_vars, that is defaulted to 1k in many cases.  That was indeed the case on my server, and resulted in my POST data getting truncated at 1k name/value pairs.

I added the following line to php.ini and rebooted Apache and now everything is good.

```
max_input_vars=3000
```